# I want to get file content and put each line in item of array

Tags: c++, file

I have a text file, this file contain the following:

**The file content**

```
27013.
Jake lexon.
8 Gozell St.
25/7/2013.
0.
```

I want to save the content of file into array, each line saved in item of array like:
**Theoretically**

```
new array;
array[item1] = 27013.
array[item2] = Jake lexon.
array[item3] = 8 Gozell St.
array[item4] = 25/7/2013.
array[item5] = 0.
```

I tried a lot but I failed.

### Edit

The reason of using c-style array is, because I want to be familiar with both ways `c-style array` and `vector` not the easy way only `vector`.

### Edit 2

Firstly the debugger doesn't give me any error.
And this is the the code that I used.

```
fstream fs("accounts/27013.txt", ios::in);
if(fs != NULL){
    char *str[100];
    str[0] = new char[100];
    int i = 0;
    while(fs.getline(str[i],100))
    {
        i++;
        str[i] = new char[100];
        cout << str[i];
    }
    cin.ignore();
} else {
    cout << "Error.";
}
```

and the result of that code :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **AS YOU DEMAND A SOLUTION WITHOUT VECTORS.(Which I won't prefer at all)**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream fs;
    fs.open("abc.txt",ios::in);
    char *str[100];
    str[0] = new char[100];
    int i = 0;
    while(fs.getline(str[i],100))
    {
        i++;
        str[i] = new char[100];
    }
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** This assumes that each line is no longet than 100 characters(including newline) and you have no more than 100 lines.

Comment: Thanks for help, I'm trying to print any item of array, but doesn't want. please how can I print items of the array?

Comment: @LionKing you insist on a solution with arrays, and I insist that it is a terrible solution that will blow up in your face one day. If you have good reasons to require plain arrays, you should explain them in the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza by terrible you mean the approach or my solution?

Comment: any flaws in this of he ought to go with plain arrays??

Comment: @Saksham I am referring to OP's insistence on a fragile solution to a problem that has robust, trivial solutions.

Comment: @Saksham: I'm already trying to print items of the array by using `cout << str[i];` , but still does not show anything.

Comment: @LionKing coming fine for me. check the file name you are accessing. and please try debugging.

Comment: @Saksham: Please go to `Edit 2` in my question to see my answer.

Comment: change the order of i++;
        str[i] = new char[100];
        cout << str[i]; to cout << str[i];i++;
        str[i] = new char[100];. This is because you are allocating memory and without initializing it, trying to access it.

Comment: @Saksham: is it possible to print the items of the array outside of while block, and how to do that ?

Comment: yes. you have the final count of items in variable i. run a for loop using that i. it would be great if you could please upvote my answer as well

Answer (score 3):

The approach is straighforward:

```
// container
vector<string> array;

// read file line by line and for each line (std::string)
string line;
while (getline(file, line))
{
   array.push_back(line);
}

// that's it
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read each line into a `vector` of `strings`, using [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::ifstream the_file("the_file_name.txt");

std::string s;
std::vector<std::string> lines;
while (std::getline(the_file, s))
{
    lines.push_back(s);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do so by using c-style `char array[]` without vector?

Comment: @LionKing it would be possible, but too much of a pain to be a viable solution.

Comment: I know I bothering you, but forgive me, can you tell me an example by using c-style `char array[]`, if you can do.

Comment: @LionKing you would need an array of `char` arrays, and you would have to know how many lines are in the file beforehand. You would also need to know the length of each line. It really isn't worth it.