# Runtime error: _block_type_is_valid(phead- nblockuse)

Tags: c++, dynamic-variables

Firstly, I will show you my code.

```
std::ifstream file("accounts/22816.txt");
if(file){
   char *str[50];
   int count=0;
   str[0] = new char[50];
   while(file.getline(str[count], 50)){
      count++;
      str[count] = new char[50];
   }
   for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
      std::cout << str[i] << std::endl;
   }
   delete[] str;  // Here is the problem
}
```

**The behavior of the previous code is:**

- Read the content of text file line by line.
- Save each line in item of the 2D array.
- Print the items of the 2D array.
- Finally, delete the array from memory << `and this reason of the
  problem`.

When test my application always give me runtime error message `_block_type_is_valid(phead- nblockuse).`

I know the problem because this `delete[] str;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str` is an array of pointers, each of those pointers pointing to a dynamically allocated array.

You need to loop over it and call `delete []` on each element.

```
for(int i=0; i < count; ++i){
  delete [] str[i];
}
```

**Note**: I have already provided OP with [an example using `std::vector`, `std::string` and `std::getline`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905636/i-want-to-get-file-content-and-put-each-line-in-item-of-array/17905666#17905666).